# Jenkins release plugin with promoted build parameter

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use the "Promoted Build Parameter" parameter type in Jenkins release plugin. What I am trying to do is let a user, who intends to initiate a Release build, select an existing promoted build, and then perform the release build on the same SVN revision number, that the selected promoted build was built on. However, I am struggling to understand how to get the svn revision number that was used during the run of the selected promoted build and pass it to the release build target command (maven). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use SVN CLI, jenkinsg plugin will not be sufficient

```
svn info | grep "Revision" | awk '{print $2}'
```